# Setting an execution's local variable according to the flow led to the sub-process

Tags: bpmn, camunda

I have a BPMN process with a sub-process within it. There are different flows leading to the sub-process. And I want to know, once inside the sub-process' execution, which flow has led to the current execution.

To this end I think variables could be handy. So I conducted a test in which I wrote a couple of scripts for flow's listener leading to the sup-process.

```
execution.setVariableLocal("V", "Expecting it to be local to the sub-process' execution");
```

But it turned out that `execution` points to the outer/parent process and thus the variable was set in parent scope.

So is there anyway to set an execution local variable from outside?

Comment: So you tried to use an execution listener on the `take` event for each of the incoming sequence flows. Is that correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest approach (basically use `getVariable` instead of `getVariableLocal`):

1. Add an execution listener to the `take` event of the sequence flows of interest
2. In the execution listener, perform

   ```
   execution.setVariableLocal("flowTaken", execution.getCurrentTransitionId());
   ```
3. Access it in the sub process via

   ```
   execution.getVariable("flowTaken");
   ```

If it has to be a local variable in the sub process:

1. Add an execution listener to the `take` event of the sequence flows of interest
2. In the execution listener, perform

   ```
   execution.setVariableLocal("flowTaken", execution.getCurrentTransitionId());
   ```
3. In the BPMN 2.0 XML, define a [variable input mapping](http://docs.camunda.org/7.3/guides/user-guide/#process-engine-process-variables-inputoutput-variable-mapping) for the subprocess:

   ```
   <subProcess ...>
     <extensionElements>
       <camunda:inputOutput>
         <camunda:inputParameter name="flowTakenAsSubprocessLocalVariable">${flowTaken}</camunda:inputParameter>
       </camunda:inputOutput>
     </extensionElements>
     ...
   </subProcess>
   ```